# SQL script create stored procedure - importing error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, sql-scripts

My SQL script (sproc.sql):

```
use timetable_db;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetEmptyClassrooms;

delimeter |
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmptyClassrooms()
 BEGIN
   SELECT room_number,seats from classrooms WHERE room_number not in (SELECT room_number FROM timetable);
 END |
```

When I try to import it to MySQL via the phpmyadmin GUI I got the errors:

> Unexpected beginning of command. (near "delimiter" at position 0)

Sorry, the default language is not English in my MySQL. I tried to translate as precisely as I can.

I've read several posts here in S.overflow about similar errors but I couldn't solve it.

There are solutions to solve this, but not much help because in the end I want to use only the "my db name . sql" script including all the create tables, insert rows...etc and of course the create procedures, everything in one, simply importable file.

I tried:

- remove the delimiter statements, leaving the '|' or '//' or '$$' there
- remove delimiter and delimiter character
  using ';' instead of '|' or '//' or '$$'
- removing delimiters and ;
- removing only ;
- removing tabs -> using only spaces
- trying the only the "SELECT ..." statement in mysql, it worked so I don't think it would be the problem.

I'm really a beginner in SQL but I want to improve myself.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You don't use the `DELIMITER` statement in phpMyAdmin, you enter the delimiter into a dialog field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is error in syntax which you are using. Please try below way.

```
   DROP procedure IF EXISTS `GetEmptyClassrooms`;
        DELIMITER $$
        USE `test`$$
        CREATE PROCEDURE `GetEmptyClassrooms` ()
        BEGIN
         SELECT room_number,seats from classrooms
 WHERE room_number not in (SELECT room_number FROM timetable);
        END
        $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

where **test** is the database name where you want to create the stored procedure

Comment: Your solution didn't give me any errors! :) Thx.